# Hadoop replication destination node configuration

Tags: hadoop

I have a question about replication in Hadoop, here is the situation:
I have a total of 6 nodes in 2 racks

```
  Rack 1      Rack 2
__________  __________
|        |  |        |
| Node 1 |  | Node 4 |
|        |  |        |
| Node 2 |  | Node 5 |
|        |  |        |
| Node 3 |  | Node 6 |
|        |  |        |
__________  __________
```

How to ensure that all my data are safe if one entire rack fail over?

Is it a way to configure the **replication destination node** ?

In this situation, with a replication factor equal to 3, a data could be saved on only 1 rack. 
Node 1 replicates to Node 2 and 3, or node 5 replicates to 4 and 6 for exemple. So if one entire rack fail over, i will loss some data.

```
  Rack 1      Rack 2
__________  __________
|        |  |        |
| Node 1 |  | Node 4 |
|    v   |  |   ^    |
| Node 2 |  | Node 5 |
|    v   |  |   v    |
| Node 3 |  | Node 6 |
|        |  |        |
__________  __________
```

What I want to do, for example for the node 1, is to force the replication at least 1 time on Node 4 or 5 or 6

```
  Rack 1      Rack 2
__________  __________
|        |  |        |
| Node 1 |  | Node 4 |
|    v   \  |   ^    |
| Node 2 |\-->Node 5 |
|        |  | /      |
| Node 3 <---/Node 6 |
|        |  |        |
__________  __________
```

One way would be to set the replication factor to 4, but this solution is not scalable enough.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop has a feature called "rack awareness" which solves this problem. If you configure Hadoop to be rack aware, then HDFS will ensure that at least one replicant goes to each rack in your two rack scenario: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html

To enable rack awareness, you must have either a Java class or external script through which a node reports to which rack it belongs.

The link above gives examples, but the exact details depend on your network configuration.